# Django - TestCase - response.status code failing

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

Hello everyone out there,

I'm starting my journey trough django test-code. The start is not great.

I'm starting some very basic testing ( tough important) as follows:

```
from django.test import TestCase, SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your tests here.

class RegistryTest(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_homepage_status(self):
        response = self.client.get('Registry/search/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_homepage_url_name(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('search'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_homepage_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('Registry/search/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'registry/search_registry.html')
```

here is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

app_name = 'registry'

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', search, name='search'),

    #customerSupplier
    path('customerSupplier/detail/<int:idCS>/', detail_customerSupplier, name='detail_customerSupplier'),
    path('customerSupplier/new/', new_customerSupplier, name='new_customerSupplier'),
]
```

this is my search view from views.py:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            azienda = form.cleaned_data['Company']
            testo   = form.cleaned_data['RagSociale']
            tipo    = form.cleaned_data['Tipologia']

            result = CustomerSupplier.search(azienda, testo, tipo)
            return render(request, 'registry/search_registry.html', {'form': form, 'CustomerSupplierList':result })

    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render(request, 'registry/search_registry.html', {'form': form })
```

this is the mail urls.py of the project forlder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

app_name = 'registry'

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', search, name='search'),

    #customerSupplier
    path('customerSupplier/detail/<int:idCS>/', detail_customerSupplier, name='detail_customerSupplier'),
    path('customerSupplier/new/', new_customerSupplier, name='new_customerSupplier'),
]
```

when I run the test i get back this error:

> python manage.py test Registry System check identified no issues (0
> silenced). FFE
> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_homepage_url_name (tests.RegistryTest)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/carloc/Projects/100_CogniSpa/gestionale-cogni/src/Registry/tests.py",
> line 13, in test_homepage_url_name
> response = self.client.get(reverse('search'))   File "/home/carloc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py",
> line 90, in reverse
> return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))   File "/home/carloc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 660, in _reverse_with_prefix
> raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function
> or pattern name.
>
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_homepage_status (tests.RegistryTest)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/carloc/Projects/100_CogniSpa/gestionale-cogni/src/Registry/tests.py",
> line 10, in test_homepage_status
> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) AssertionError: 404 != 200
>
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_homepage_template (tests.RegistryTest)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/carloc/Projects/100_CogniSpa/gestionale-cogni/src/Registry/tests.py",
> line 18, in test_homepage_template
> self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'registry/search_registry.html')   File
> "/home/carloc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
> line 639, in assertTemplateUsed
> self.fail(msg_prefix + "No templates used to render the response") AssertionError: No templates used to render the response
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 3 tests in 0.008s
>
> FAILED (failures=2, errors=1)

I'm kind of lost...
the template is located at templates/registry/search_registry.html in the app, but still it says no template as been used for the response.

Any help?

thank you very much.

Carlo

Comment: Please show the project's `urls.py` where you use `include()`. Note that `test_homepage_status` is failing because it's returning 404 instead of 200. Fix that first, before you worry about the template test.

Comment: Move the final `return render(...)` outside of the `else` block - at the moment, the search view won't return a response for a post request when the form isn't valid.

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from Registry.views import default

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('Registry/', include('Registry.urls', namespace='registry')),


    # path('', default),
]`  Sorry if it's not perfectly formatted

Comment: here is the main urls.py from the project forlder. `path('Registry/', include('Registry.urls', namespace='registry')),`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there, instead of adding code to the comments.

Comment: @Alasdair shouldn't it work for the GET method? anyway I tried to comment out the 'else:' but still fails....

Comment: The URLs should have a leading slash, e.g. `self.client.get('/Registry/search/')`, or you can use `reverse('registry:search')` as Arakkal suggested.

Comment: *shouldn't it work for the GET method?* - yes, changing this won't affect the GET request, I was just pointing out that it's a problem. The `form = SearchForm()` should still be in the else block so don't comment it out. Move the return outside of the else block.

Answer (score 1):

OK solved.

2 issues worth pointing out:

**first**: the client.get() method should be:

```
response = self.client.get('/your/path/')
```

and not:

```
response = self.client.get('your/path/')
```

that first leading slash is important.

**Second**: In my case I was testing with 'SimpleTestCase' which does not allow for connections to the database, which my view required in order to process the test correctly. Therefore I switched to `class RegistryTest(TestCase): .....`

By making this corrections, the third and final test ('assertTemplateUsed') passed the test as well.

Thank you guys very much for the hint. It really helped